# Lambda causing AttributeError

Tags: python, lambda, odoo, odoo-8

I have this piece of code that fetches an id of a sale team if the person is in one, else it returns None.

```
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    xx_section_id = fields.Many2one('crm.case.section', string='Invoice template', required=True,
                                default=lambda self: self._get_sales_team())

    @api.model
    def _get_sales_team(self):
        ids = self.env['crm.case.section'].search([('member_ids', 'in', self._uid)])
        if len(ids) != 1:
            # Has no sales team or more than one
            return None
        return ids[0]
```

For some reason this works in my local environment but not on the server. The error occurs when I try to install the module. The server gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

And in the logging it states:

```
2016-12-06 19:39:06,662 2005 ERROR None openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/glenn/Documents/Work/odoo80_vzwwebcrm_tst/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/Users/glenn/Documents/Work/odoo80_vzwwebcrm_tst/openerp/http.py", line 1415, in _dispatch_nodb
    func, arguments = self.nodb_routing_map.bind_to_environ(request.httprequest.environ).match()
  File "/Users/glenn/.virtualenvs/odoo8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1430, in match
    raise NotFound()
NotFound: 404: Not Found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Given how xx_section_id  is named it would appear that it's meant to be an id. But if _get_sales_team returns None ...? Could it be that this condition should be flagged somehow?

Comment: @BillBell Returning None type is used to mark the absence of a value, it stays empty when returning None

Answer (score 0):

For the case len(ids) == 0, the script tries to 'return ids[0]'.

Depending on the result value of 'ids', you condition should be:

```
if ids:
```

or

```
if len(ids) > 0:
```

Comment: It only accepts one, hence the condition check if not equals